# How to insert a new control flow task between existing tasks within an SSIS package?

Tags: ssis

Is it possible to insert a data flow task between two existing tasks in an SSIS package?

I have a data flow that is in pretty good shape. During testing the data flow logic, I found that I need an additional data flow task between existing ones.

Is it possible to insert a new task between the existing tasks?

Answer (score 5):

#### Solution:

You need to delete the **`Precedence Constraint`** connecting the two Control Flow tasks and then drag and drop the new task between the two existing tasks. Connect the precedence constraint from the first task to the new task and the precedence constraint from the new task to the existing second task.

*`Precedence Constraint`* is the arrow between two control flow tasks that denotes the direction of the flow. The arrow could appear in *`green`*, *`red`* or *`blue`* colors depending on the condition used to direct the flow.

#### Caution:

If there is an expression on the *`Precedence Constraint`*, you have to note down what the expression is before deleting the precedence constraint. You may need to use that expression again after introducing the new task.

#### SSIS 2012 package illustrating the steps:

Assume that you have an SSIS package named *`SO_6115881.dtsx`*. Within the package, you have two data flow tasks on the Control Flow tab. Below shown screenshot indicates that there are not expression or constraints on the Precedence Constraint (green arrow).

[image: Two Data Flow Tasks without expression]

If you had an expression defined on the *Precedence Constraint*, the letters fx will appear on the precedence constraint.

[image: Two Data Flow Tasks with expression]

You can double-click the precedence constraint to view the *`Precedence Constraint Editor`* to make note of the expression used. Here, the precedence constraint uses the expression `@[User::IsValid] == True` to verify if the package variable `@[User::IsValid]` evaluates to true or not.

[image: Precedence Constraint Editor]

Let's assume that there are no expressions between the two existing control flow tasks. To delete the precedence constraint, you click on it and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or right-click on the precedence constraint and click *`Delete`*.

[image: Delete Precedence Constraint]

After deleting the precedence constraint, drag and drop the next control flow task between the two existing tasks. Drag the precedence constraint from the task `Data Flow Task 1` and connect it to the new task `New Data Flow Task`.

[image: Connect first task to second task]

Drag the precedence constraint from the new task `New Data Flow Task` and connect it to the task `Data Flow Task 2`. You should now have the new control flow task successfully added in between two existing tasks. If you had an expression, double-click the appropriate precedence constraint to add the expression.

[image: Control Flow tab with new task]

Comment: Can i do it without delete the existing Precedence Constraint? The method above is good if not too many control task.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that in 2021 this is still a problem. I hate moving arrows because of this exact problem with constraint expressions.